# Лишние строки в css в написание?

Tags: css

Скажите вы пишите ли когда строки когда в этом вроде бы нет необходимости. К примеру нужно разместить картинку которая должна повторится один раз, но понимаешь что она настолько большая что маловерятно что кто то увидит повтор

```
background-image: url("../images/very_big_pic.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

и просто не используете

```
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Как вариант можно так написать: `background: url("../images/very_big_pic.jpg") no-repeat;`

Comment: так оно понятно, просто пишите или нет если в этом на первый взгляд нету крайней необходимости

Comment: Мне кажется, лучше написать. Лично я всегда пишу.

Comment: я тоже пишу, но подумал а вдруг это мини  параноика